# Thread safety with CopyOnArrayList in servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, copyonwritearraylist

I'm just starting with servlets & threading. Final instance variables are thread-safe and so is CopyOnArrayList. Why is the following code NOT thread-safe (it's final + I used CopyOnArrayList)?

```
@WebServlet("/index.html")
public class CatServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static String VIEW = "/WEB-INF/JSP/index.jsp";
    **private final CopyOnWriteArrayList <Cat> l = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();**

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        l.add(new Cat("Dean", 7));
        l.add(new Cat("Sam", 7));
        l.add(new Cat("Pixie", 0));
        request.setAttribute("catList", l);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW).forward(request, response);
    }
```

JSP code:

```
<c:forEach var="cat" items="${catList}" >
    <li>${cat.name}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

First I get 3 Cat instances. When refreshing I get 6, then 9, 12, etc. Why?
The problem does not occur when I declare the CopyOnWriteArrayList within the doGet method, nor when I do it with a simple array. I do not understand the logic behind it: a final instance variable and CopyOnWriteArrayList should be thread-safe. Thank you all for clarifying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding 3 elements in your list each time you refresh the page since you add them in your `doGet` method.

If you declare your list in your `doGet` method, it will be erased each time the method is called.

There is no thread safety involved here.

Answer (score 1):

It is `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, not `EraseOnWriteArrayList`. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` creates a new copy each time it is written, so that existing iterators continue operating on the old version. The list is not erased each time a doGet is called, so it is just added at the end. You just have unnecessary overhead of internal copying each time you add a new `Cat`.